# I'm getting error in this code.The idea is to calculate the count of occurence of how many times that word repeats in the given paragraph

Tags: javascript

```
function countWords(){  
    s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    document.getElementById("wordcount").value = s.split(' ').length;
      }

  <textarea name="inputString" cols="50" rows="4">
      Text to count
   </textarea>
   <input type="button" name="Convert" value="Count Words" 
   onClick="countWords();"> 
   <input name="wordcount" type="text" value="" size="6">
```

I am getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null.

Could please help me to solve the error?

Comment: Your textarea has a name, not an ID. Also, you should get the `.value` of `<input>`s, and the `.textContent` of `<textarea>`s...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an exception because you only set the name of your last input element, not the id. `document.getElementById` needs the id property, not the name.

You should change name to id (or add Id) in the last line of the html:

`<input id="wordcount" type="text" value="" size="6">`

EDIT: also in the first line in your textarea:
`<textarea id="inputString" cols="50" rows="4">Text to count</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

On your html code, you have set the `name` attribute on `textarea` and `input` tags but have not set `id` attribute on `textarea` and `input` tags.

So it will throw error on script when getting the element using id.

It is needed to set the id of the `<textarea>` and `<input>` tag as follows to make your script work.

```js
function countWords() {
  let s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
  s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
  s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");
  s = s.replace(/\n /, "\n");
  document.getElementById("wordcount").value = s.split(' ').length;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputString" cols="50" rows="4">Text to count</textarea>
<input type="button" name="Convert" value="Count Words" onClick="countWords();">
<input id="wordcount" type="text" value="" size="6">
```